# How to directly open the "setting window" for Windows Terminal on Win 11?

Tags: command-line, windows-11

Is there a commandline argument for `wt` that can summon the following GUI window for settings? The full list of CLI flags is documented [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/command-line-arguments?tabs=windows#command-line-syntax), but I failed to find anything relevant.

[image]

---

The `wt.exe` process offered the following flags, none of which has to do with opening up the setting window.

[image]

Comment: If there isn't a solution, you might be able to call some VBScript which launches `wt.exe` and then passes the appropriate key combination to get you into the settings. Pretty hacky, but might be better than nothing.

Comment: Sounds good. An easier (but not as much robust) way is to directly edit the JSON file. Across Win 10 and Win 11 OS, for my user account, the JSON file is locaed at: `C:/Users/<username>/AppData/Local/Packages/Microsoft.WindowsTerminal_8wekyb3d8bbwe/LocalState/settings.json`

This address seems to be stable for WT for a whole year or so, since late 2020.